# Исчезает вкладка с характеристиками товара при смене языка

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, wpml

[image: Характеристики есть]
[image: Характеристик нет]
[image: Админка изнутри]
Всем привет. Собственно вопрос в оглавлении. Магазин на двух языках, переводился плагином WPML, при смене языков пропадает вкладка со списком атрибутов товара. Все атрибуты и рубрики товаров переведены, все товары переведены. В админке товара на проблемном языке атрибуты заблокированы с пометкой "редактировать можно только товар на языке оригинала". Короче есть стойкое ощущение где-то просто нужно поставить галочку "Выводить описание товара на укр языке", только вот где ее искать?

Comment: Поставить https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-multilingual/ и перевести атрибуты. Так же в настройках WMPL настроить что переводить

Comment: Так и есть. Плагин стоит, все атрибуты переведены

Answer (score 0):

В общем баг был на уровне плагина перевода, скорее всего. Характеристики не отображались только на том товаре языковя версию которого создавалась второй через плагин woocommerce-multilingual. Но стоило открыть проблемный товар в стандартном редакторе товаров и просто его пересохранить так проблема сразу исчезала. В общем дальше буду уже разбираться со службой поддержки самого плагина перевода.